# Сделал простые табы на js, хотелось бы услышать критику

Tags: javascript, html, css, инспекция-кода

```js
let tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');

let sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

for(let i =0; i<tabs.length; i++){
   tabs[i].onclick = tabclick
}

function tabclick(event){
  let tab = event.target;
  let tabId = tab.dataset.id;

  for(let k =0; k<tabs.length; k++){
    tabs[k].classList.remove('active');
    tabs[tabId-1].classList.add('active');

    sections[k].classList.remove('active');
    sections[tabId-1].classList.add('active'); 

  }
}
```

```css
.tabs{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tab{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tab.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
}
.output{
  clear:both;
}
.section {
  display: none;
}
.section.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab active" data-id="1">tab1</li>
  <li class="tab" data-id="2">tab2</li>
  <li class="tab" data-id="3">tab3</li>
</ul>
<div class="output">
  <section class="section active">section1</section>
  <section class="section">section2</section>
  <section class="section">section3</section>
</div>
```

Comment: можно не вешать обработчик на каждый таб, а повесить 1, на общего родителя. Говорят так будет легче для браузера

Comment: Не очень хорошо привязывать логику к разметке. Порядок следования `.section` может быть разный. Лучше к каждому `.section` сделать data-attribute. К тому же, плохо привязывать событие через `onclick `. Лучше через `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 3):

В основном замечания относятся к использованию современной версии JavaScript вместо старого ES5.

```js
const tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');  
const sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section'); 

[...tabs].forEach(tab => tab.addEventListener('click', tabClick));

function tabClick(event) {
  const tabId = event.target.dataset.id;

  [...tabs].forEach((tab, i) => {
    tab.classList.remove('active');
    sections[i].classList.remove('active');
  })

  tabs[tabId - 1].classList.add('active');
  sections[tabId - 1].classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.tabs{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tab{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tab.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
}
.output{
  clear:both;
}
.section {
  display: none;
}
.section.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab active" data-id="1">tab1</li>
  <li class="tab" data-id="2">tab2</li>
  <li class="tab" data-id="3">tab3</li>
</ul>
<div class="output">
  <section class="section active">section1</section>
  <section class="section">section2</section>
  <section class="section">section3</section>
</div>
```

- Переменные не переназначаются, поэтому лучше использовать `const`
- Цикл `for` можно заменить на метод массива
- Установка `onclick` листенера лучше делать с помощью `addEventListener`
- Для названий функций и переменных в JS принято использовать *camelCase*
- Неиспользуемая переменная `let tab = event.target;`
- Добавление класса `.active` достаточно вызывать один раз, поэтому лучше всего вынести её из цикла

Comment: в вашем случае можно не вешать обработчик на каждый таб, а использовать делегирование

Comment: Это зависит от кейса. В случае если содержимым таба будет не один элемент, а например иконка + текст + текст, то функция делегирования начнет разростатся чтобы предусмотреть все условия. Но в целом да, с точки зрения производительности, делегирование будет лучшим вариантом

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу смысла использовать массив вовсе.

Вот мой пример реализации:

```js
$('.tabs-block .tab-link').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    var parentTabs = $(this).closest('.tabs-block');
    parentTabs.find('.tab-link.active, .tab-content.active').removeClass('active');
    var elemIndex = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    parentTabs.find('.tab-content').eq(elemIndex).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
body {background: #333;}

.tabs-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-link-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4184f3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-link {
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #bbb;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-link:not(.active):hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.tab-link.active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  color: #fff;
}

.tab-content-block {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  min-height: calc(50px - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fefefe;
  color: #333;
}

.tab-content:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}


/* horizontal */

.tabs-block:not(.-vertical) .tab-link-block {
  height: 50px;
}

.tabs-block:not(.-vertical) .tab-link-block::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.tabs-block:not(.-vertical) .tab-link {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: calc(50px - 20px);
  max-width: calc(150px - 20px);
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.tabs-block:not(.-vertical) .tab-link.active {
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 #f4b142 inset;
}

.tabs-block:not(.-vertical) .tab-link:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* horizontal */


/* vertical */

.tabs-block.-vertical {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.tabs-block.-vertical .tab-link {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.tabs-block.-vertical .tab-link.active {
  box-shadow: -3px 0 0 0 #f4b142 inset;
}


/* vertical */

.tab-link {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  transition: all linear .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs-block">
  <div class="tab-link-block">
    <div class="tab-link active">Первая вкладка</div>
    <div class="tab-link">Вторая вкладка</div>
    <div class="tab-link">Третья вкладка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content-block">
    <div class="tab-content active">1</div>
    <div class="tab-content">2</div>
    <div class="tab-content">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="tabs-block -vertical">
  <div class="tab-link-block">
    <div class="tab-link active">Первая вкладка</div>
    <div class="tab-link">Вторая вкладка</div>
    <div class="tab-link">Третья вкладка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content-block">
    <div class="tab-content active">1</div>
    <div class="tab-content">2</div>
    <div class="tab-content">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Во-первых: Вы использовали jQuery, что как бы не относится к данному вопросу напрямую
Во-вторых: То что массивы явно не использованы это не значит что Вы их не использовали вовсе.  
`parentTabs` - это массив всех элементов.
`parentTabs.find` - это метод поиска в массиве.

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, про JQ можно говорить много, так что сразу закроем тему. Про find не нашёл инфы, что ведётся поиск в массиве, про DOM - везде.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/traversing/findFilter.js#L54
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/core/init.js#L118
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/core.js#L272

Answer (score -1):

Ну если придерживаться советов из комментариев, получается такой код:

```js
let tabs = document.querySelector('.tabs');
let sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

tabs.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let target = e.target;

  if(target.classList.contains('tab')) {
    let tabId = target.dataset.id;
    let section = sections[tabId - 1];
    let activeTab = document.querySelector('.tab.active');
    let activeSection = document.querySelector('.section.active');
    
    activeTab.classList.remove('active');
    activeSection.classList.remove('active');

    target.classList.add('active');
    section.classList.add('active');
  }
})
```

```css
.tabs{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tab{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tab.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
}
.output{
  clear:both;
}
.section {
  display: none;
}
.section.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab active" data-id="1">tab1</li>
  <li class="tab" data-id="2">tab2</li>
  <li class="tab" data-id="3">tab3</li>
</ul>
<div class="output">
  <section class="section active">section1</section>
  <section class="section">section2</section>
  <section class="section">section3</section>
</div>
```